# DirectX frame work failing to create swapchain and device

Tags: c++, directx, hwnd, directx-10

I am having major issues with my DirectX10 frame work code.

The code stops in the `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()` function on the `ID3D10Device` argument and outputs:

> pD3DDevice CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found

I am getting this on almost everything, my error handler, `pSwapChain`, `pDepthStencilView` etc. etc.

My code is structuered as: `dxGeometry -> dxD3D -> dxSystem -> winMain`

Here is my code: [dxD3D.h](http://pastebin.com/d0RMmNvK), [dxSystem.h](http://pastebin.com/a28BV8AX).

Thanks for the help, this has been a problem for the last two days, I've tried almost everything, but I am unable to see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase that, pD3DDevice is not defined, so it can't be watched from the debug editor.
m_pD3DDevice is defined according to the code.

As for the actual reason it's failing, the code seems fine, you'll need to check the HRESULT and use the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205278(v=vs.85).aspx direct3d 10 error codes to determine what's wrong.